# Ajax JQuery responses in a specific order

Tags: ajax, sorting, jquery, arraylist

I'm using an AJAX request (with jQuery) to retrieve data from a XML file. I was wandering what is the best way to sort the result in a specific order before printing them on the page.

the problem is that I'm calculating a distance between a starting position and the
position of every item in the XML and then append that distance (in jQuery) to each item.

Everything is working except the items are listed on the page related to their order in the original XML.

Now, what I would like to do is to sort this list from the smallest distance to the biggest before adding them to the page...

Is there any sort of "sort-by" of "order-by" function in jQuery/AJAX (or does that make any sense)?

So far, here's what I have:

```
$.ajax({
type: "GET",
url: "blc.xml",
dataType: "xml",
success: parseXml
});

function parseXml(xml) {
$(xml).find("marker").each(function() {

var transit = $(this).find("transit").text();
var type = $(this).find("type").text();
var codepostal = $(this).find("codepostal").text();
var lat2 = $(this).find("lat").text();
var lng2 = $(this).find("lng").text();
var maxDist = 10;

if (newLatLon < maxDist) {
$("#list").append('<p id="' + transit + '">' + type + codepostal + '</p>');

 $("#" + transit).append(document.createTextNode(" " + newLatLon + " KM"));

}
```

Thanks for your input!
(Please not that I don't want to be able to drag items in any order (as with jQuery UI), just to print them in a specific order).

Comment: What type are the values that you're trying to sort?

Comment: (Calculated) Numbers as in "10", "9.85", "6.5", etc. (without quotes).

Answer (score 0):

[Tablesorter](http://tablesorter.com/docs/#Demo) is a jquery plug-in for building sortable tables.  [There](http://flexigrid.info/) [are](http://www.trirand.com/blog/jqgrid/jqgrid.html) [many](http://datatables.net/), [take your pick](http://www.google.com.tw/search?aq=f&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=jquery%20sort%20table).

Comment: Thanks @Jason but I guess those plug-ins needs the data to be structured in a table (which is not my case...) But even if a put the data in a table, since I'm not looking to sort the data once they are printed on the page but rather to sort them before they are printed on the page, isn't a plug-in a bit overkill?

Comment: I don't understand, do you need to display this data on the page?  If so I don't think s plug in if over kill

Comment: Right...I guess! Anyway, I went with the [Tablesorter](http://tablesorter.com/docs/#Demo) plugin as suggested by @Jason. I'll let you know if I can come up with a better solution. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Can you just use the JavaScript function `sort()`?

```
function sortNumber(a,b)
{
    return a - b;
}

var n = [10, 5, 40, 25, 100, 1];
var sorted = n.sort(sortNumber)
// sorted = [1, 5, 10, 25, 40, 100]
```

EDIT: Added sortNumber function.